# Can someone tell me what the purpose of load immediate is in this MIPS program?

Tags: assembly, mips

I've been working on an introduction to MIPS tutorial from my university, and we're to look at the code and try to understand each line.

I understand what the load immediate function does, i.e. it loads the 2nd value/value from register into the first register.

What I don't understand is it's purpose in this program. Although removing it seems to cause the program to fail.

http://www.inf.ed.ac.uk/teaching/courses/inf2c-cs/labs/hexOut.s

It first loads 4 into $v0, then 5 after prompting the user for imput, then adds $v0 to $zero and stores it in $s0 before loading $v0 back to 4 again. etc. etc.

But I can't see any purpose in doing this. It appears that's the only time $v0 is used, but they keep changing it's value throughout. Secondly, why can't you simply write "li $s0, 5" instead of changing $v0 to 5 and then doing the "add  $s0, $zero, $v0" command?

Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: Click - just noticed a note on Mars when I hovered over syscall. It carries out whatever instruction is held in register $x where x is the value in $v0? And if there's no value in $v0, then it asks the user for input, is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

`syscall` is a generic interface. You tell it specifically what to do by loading an agreed-upon number into `$v0` before calling it. In this example / target environment, `4` is apparently an operation that writes out the string at the address in `$a0` and `5` is an operation that gets input from the user. That output has to go somewhere and since you don't need the system call number after you've made the system call `$v0` is a fine place for the result to go.